# Numpy/Torch : Selecting elements using indices over a dimension

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

Given an array like below:

```
np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
Out[119]: 
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

I want to select a single element from each of the rows using a list of indices `[0, 2, 1, 2]` to create a `4x1` array of `[0, 5, 7, 11]`.

Is there any easy way to do this indexing. The closest I could see was the `gather` method in `pytorch`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
arr[[0,1,2,3], [0,2,1,2]]
```

or if you prefer `np.arange(4)` for the 1st indexing array.

Answer (score 1):

```py
>>> import torch
>>> import numpy as np
>>> s = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)
>>> s = torch.tensor(s)
>>> s
tensor([[ 0,  1,  2],
        [ 3,  4,  5],
        [ 6,  7,  8],
        [ 9, 10, 11]])
>>> idx = torch.tensor([0, 2, 1, 2])
>>> torch.gather(s,-1 ,idx.unsqueeze(-1))
tensor([[ 0],
        [ 5],
        [ 7],
        [11]])
```

`torch.gather(s,-1 ,idx.unsqueeze(-1))`

Answer (score 0):

Please try to run the following code.

```
import numpy as np
x = [[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]]
index_array = [0, 2, 1, 2]       
index = 0
result = []
for item in x:
    result.append(item[index_array[index]])
    index += 1
print (result)
```

Here is the result.

```
[0, 5, 7, 11]
>
```